# Minikube unable to schedule new pods due to insufficient cpu

Tags: macos, kubernetes, minikube

Currently I am playing around with Minikube and for the last couple of days, I have had several deployments and replicasets running without any issues. I deleted all of them to start over and ran into an issue where I am unable to create new pods.

I am trying to create a very basic pod with the following schema:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
  labels:
    app: mypod-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 128Mi
        cpu: 50M
```

Unfortunately this fails with the message:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  90s   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
```

Now there is nothing else running in my Minikube cluster apart from what is run by default. I installed the metrics add-on which and ran `kubectl top node`:

```
NAME       CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
minikube   293m         7%     574Mi           7%
```

I also deleted my Minikube cluster and started it with the following command: `minikube start --cpus 4 --memory 4g`

Am I missing something here, or is there anything I can do to figure out why I am unable to schedule new pods? Any help would be appreciated.

Environment details:

```
minikube version: v1.31.2
Client Version: v1.28.1
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.27.4
Macbook Air M2
```

Kind regards

Comment: please try commenting out the resource limits of nginx for debugging.

Comment: Hi, That works with getting it to run. Can you explain the reason behind the pod not being created when the limits are being set?

Comment: `kubectl describe node minikube` will tell you what's currently scheduled on the node, which might give you some insight as to what's allocating all of the available CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Limits:** A container is not allowed to use more than its resource limit.

- **CPU Limits:** The quantity expression 0.1 is equivalent to the expression 100m, which can be read as "one hundred millicpu".

  - use 1 cpu core => cpu = "1" = "1000" = "1000m"
  - use 10% of 1 cpu core => cpu = "0.1" = "100" = "100m"
- **Memory Limits:** Limits and requests for memory are measured in bytes. Pay attention to the case of the suffixes. If you request 400m of memory, this is a request for 0.4 bytes. Someone who types that probably meant to ask for 400 mebibytes (400Mi) or 400 megabytes (400M).

  - use 64 MB => memory: "64M"

**Requests:** If the node where a Pod is running has enough of a resource available, it's possible (and allowed) for a container to use more resource than its request for that resource specifies.

Now in your case, I think that your cpu configuration should not be "cpu: 50M", it should be "cpu: 0.5, or 1"

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
  labels:
    app: mypod-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 128Mi
        cpu: 0.5
```

Please update the values to find the optimum configuration.

**Ref:** https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

Comment: Thank you, the mistake I made was 'M', instead of using 'm'. Your description and solution helped me solve the issue!

Kind regards